# Android Studio Beta 0.8.1 + Crashlytics: app won't compile anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

Since downloading the new Android Studio Beta I have a problem with my (professional) apps that have the Crashlytics plugin enabled.
Since the new IDE version/Gradle version they can't compile at all anymore. It's either the `app:debugCompile` or `app:releaseCompile` proces that takes ages and never gets resolved. (Yesterday I let it compiling for 3 hours and it never finished).

I even tried setting up a fresh new Android project as a test without any additions which off course ran fine, but once I added Crashlytics the problem described earlier showed up again.

I can't be the only one with this problem, can I? Or am I missing something?

This is the Gradle file of my test project, the Crashlytics part is added with the AS plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yungpanda.testprojectfortest"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

Comment: Where can I see logs of possible failures? Since the compiling/building never stops there is no output in AS

Comment: You might try a command-line Gradle build and see what the output is.

Comment: It just hangs on 
> Configuring > 2/2 projects > Resolving dependencies':app:_debugCompile', no extra info there

Comment: Same problem here. Seems that Crashlytics repo is down or something like that

Comment: try running ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies --debug and check that it freezes on the crashlytics repo http call

Comment: I think this is the same problem you are having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574037/android-studio-beta-0-8-1-crashlytics-app-wont-compile-anymore?rq=1